# What is all the JavaScript rendered by PrimeFaces?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to understand how the flowing request works, I am new in primeFaces so please excuse me if it's too basic question.

- The request send ID and date of birth to the server, and I don't understand how it works(`onclick`, `onstart`...).
- What is the differences between `PrimeFaces.ab` and `PrimeFaces.cw`?

[image]

```html
<button id="scheduleForm:tabViewId:searchIcon" name="scheduleForm:tabViewId:searchIcon" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'scheduleForm:tabViewId:searchIcon',
update:'scheduleForm:tabViewId:panelInfoPessoal scheduleForm:postPanelGroup scheduleForm:postcons scheduleForm:infoAgendamento scheduleForm:listaAtos scheduleForm:preRegPanelGroup scheduleForm:SGCMessage',
onstart:function(cfg){loadingDlg.show();},oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){loadingDlg.hide();;}});return false;" style="align: right; width: 20%; min-width: 120px;vertical-align: middle;margin:0 auto" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text">Pesquisar</span></button><script id="scheduleForm:tabViewId:searchIcon_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('CommandButton',
'widget_scheduleForm_tabViewId_searchIcon',{id:'scheduleForm:tabViewId:searchIcon'});</script></div><div id="scheduleForm:tabViewId:tab_gov" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true"><table id="scheduleForm:tabViewId:panelLogin" style="text-align: center; font-size: 12pt; vertical-align: middle; margin:0 auto; padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 2%;">
```

Answer (score 3):

The PrimeFaces Ajax API is documented here https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/core/ajaxJavascriptApi and here https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/modules/src_primefaces.primefaces.ajax.html

`PrimeFaces.ab` is short for `PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.handle` which handles Ajax requests.
`PrimeFaces.cw` is short for `PrimeFaces.createWidget` which will create a widget (which is used by most of the PrimeFaces components, basically the JavaScript API for a component instance).

As a user of PrimeFaces components you are not required to know all the ins and outs of the core JavaScript. It will help in more complex scenarios, but as a beginner I would not focus on that.

To start of, I recommend you start with reading [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes).

Comment: Thank you I will take a look :)